# Rails isn't Magic, Where does a method live?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, methods

I have a nice piece of functional and tested Ruby code that I would like to integrate into a rails project:

```
require 'open-uri'

def shorten(url)
  open("http://is.gd/api.php?longurl=#{url}").read
rescue
  nil
end
```

I want to call the method shorten(url) from show.html.erb in the following way:

```
<% @shorturl = shorten("http://www.google.com/search?q=#{@bands.item.gsub(' ', '+')}+san+francisco") %>
```

I thought that placing the method shorten, within the model would work but it results in a **NoMethodError** (the require 'open-uri' is placed in the application_controller.rb)

```
undefined method `shorten' for #<ActionView::Base:0x1037e66a8>
```

Where should this method live? How can I get this to work? And what book or resource do you recommend that would make Rails seem less magical. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My experience has been:  if the method is dealing with database data, best to move it to Model.  Even if it is about processing data from database data, it is recommended to move it into Model if possible, to have "lean controller" and "lean view" if possible.

If the method is for generally helping to display something, then it belongs to the "helper"... for example, the `h` method is a classic example of "helping the View code".  You can add such methods to the application helper file, which is `app/helpers/application_helpers.rb`

If it is not dealing with view and not dealing with data from the database, then you might consider it being a method of that controller class, or even a method of the application controller if it is very central to your application and should be inherited by all controllers.

Answer (score 2):

Well, if it's a method that belongs to the model, either it's a class method or an instance method :

**Class method**

```
#some controller
MyModel.method(...)

#MyModel
def self.method(...)
  ...
end
```

**Instance method**

```
#some controller
@myInstance = MyModel.find...(...)
@myInstance.method(...)

#MyModel
def method(...)
  ...
end
```

If it's not to be put in any model, I recommend an helper like 動靜能量 said.

Answer (score 0):

動靜能量's answer is pretty good so I'll just add that if you want to learn some rails check out this free online tutorial that takes you step by step through building a Twitter clone: http://railstutorial.org/book

Several books I've read say to learn Rails first (including the above link) but I think this is a horrible idea and really, really bad advice. If you don't understand Ruby then you can't understand what is Rails "magic" and what's just standard Ruby.

So my advice is to learn Ruby first then learn Rails. It will be MUCH less frustrating and magical seeming. Here are some of my favorite books on Ruby:

[Programming Ruby 1.9](http://pragprog.com/titles/ruby3/programming-ruby-1-9)
[Metaprogramming Ruby](http://pragprog.com/titles/ppmetr/metaprogramming-ruby)
[Refactoring: Ruby Edition](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321603508)

I love [Pragmatic](http://pragprog.com/) because the authors get a lot more money for their efforts and everyone involved seems to really care about the quality of their products.

Comment: I'd really like to know what jerk (and coward for not saying why) voted down this answer. The guy asked for some good books and resources. The person that voted down this answer apparently hates knowledge... and freedom... and kittens and rainbows!

Comment: That's why I quit answering questions here. Some a-holes just go around down voting questions they don't like or disagree with. You can be right but if they disagree they'll down vote. I think it's kids. Oh and +1 for making me laugh.